# XSLT node filtering with identity template not working

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to extract specific nodes (`trk`) from a GPX file (XML coded waypoint and tracks) with a stylesheet. The other nodes `wpt` should be discarded.

The XML is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creator="nüvi 2595" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv2.xsd">
<wpt lat="55.55555" lon="10.0000">
    <name>Waypoint</name>
    <extensions>
        <WaypointExtension>
            <Categories>
                <Category>Museum</Category>
            </Categories>
        </WaypointExtension>
    </extensions>
</wpt>
<trk>
    <name>Sample Track</name>
    <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="55.5555" lon="0.0000">
            <ele>-39.76</ele>
            <time>2011-10-04T12:44:53Z</time>
            <extensions>
                <TrackPointExtension>
                    <course>259.76</course>
                </TrackPointExtension>
            </extensions>
        </trkpt>
        <trk/>
    </trkseg>
 </trk>
</gpx>
```

My stylesheet is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<!-- IdentityTransform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="wpt"/>
```

Applying the stylesheet (xsltproc on OS X) always copy the **complete** file ignoring the last wpt template. However when removing the metadata attributes of the root `gpx` node the translation works!

What is wrong with my XSLT file?

Answer (score 0):

Your document has a default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"`) that your template doesn't match against.

Define a namespace prefix in your template for this namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:g="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
```

Then add it to your template:

```
<xsl:template match="g:wpt"/>
```

and you will filter out the `wpt` elements (in the default namespace) as you desired.

Altogether:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:g="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <!-- IdentityTransform -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="g:wpt"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was naively assuming that I can ignore namespace definitions. Garmin has several extra namespace definition for their GPX files but including the general GPX namespace is ok for this simple filter task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by 'metadata' attributes you probably mean the `xmlns="http://www.topographix.com/GPX/1/1"` declaration at least, probably others too. That's not an attribute, it's a default namespace declaration.

What that means is, your `wpt` element belongs to that namespace, as it's declared as the default. However, you have no default namespace declaration in your stylesheet, so the `wpt` element it's trying to match does not have a namespace, and essentially doesn't have the same fully qualified name.

When you remove the `xmlns=".."` namespace declaration from your source, the `wpt` element loses it's namespace, and then CAN be matched by your template.

You have two possible solutions- add a default namespace to your stylesheet, essentially just a copy of the `xmlns=".."` that's in your source, or add namespace with a prefix such as `xmlns:gpx=".."` and match `gpx:wpt` instead of just `wpt`.